# Why java.nio.SocketChannel not send data (Jdiameter)?

Tags: java, sockets, mobicents, restcomm, diameter-protocol

I create simple diameter client and server ([Link to sources](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr090EVo7eXYzNjVGdyVjhtX28/edit?usp=sharing)). Client must send 10000 ccr messages, but in wireshark i see only ~300 ccr messages will be sended. Other messages raised timeouts on client. I run server and client on different computers with windows 7. I found in JDiameter sources  [line where jdiameter sended ccr (line 280)](https://code.google.com/p/jdiameter/source/browse/core/jdiameter/impl/src/main/java/org/jdiameter/client/impl/transport/tcp/TCPTransportClient.java#280) and i think in case when sending buffer of socket is full ccr not sended. I add before line 280 this code

```
while(bytes.hasRemaining())
```

Client send ~9900 ccr, but very slow.I tested client on other diameter server wroted on c++, client(on jdiameter without my changes) send ~7000 ccr, but this server hosted on debian.

I don't know ways to solve this problem, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If the sender's send returns zero, it means the sender's socket send buffer is full, which in turn means the receiver's socket receive buffer is full, which in turn means that the receiver is reading slower than the sender is sending.

So speed up the receiver.

NB In non-blocking mode, merely looping around the `write()` call while it returns zero is not adequate. If `write()` returns zero you must:

1. Deregister the channel for `OP_READ` and register it for `OP_WRITE`
2. Return to the select loop.
3. When `OP_WRITE` fires, do the write again. This time, if it *doesn't* return zero, deregister `OP_WRITE`, and (probably, according to your requirements) register `OP_READ`.

Note that keeping the channel registered for `OP_WRITE` all the time isn't correct either. A socket channel is almost always writable, meaning there is almost always space in the socket send buffer. What you're interested in is the *transistion* between *not*-writable and writable.

Comment: I increase receiving and sending socket buffers to 1mb in TcpTransportClient.intialize: 
  socketChannel.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(size);
  socketChannel.socket().setSendBufferSize(size);
And add this code to sendMessage:
  rc = socketChannel.write(bytes);
  if (rc == 0)
    while (bytes.hasRemaining()) {
      Thread.sleep(10l);
      rc = socketChannel.write(bytes);
   }

It's work fine with diameter server on c++ on debian, but on jdiameter server problem not solved.

Comment: @MadCrank Raising the buffer sizes doesn't speed up the receiver, and it really only defers the problem. You haven't posted your source code, but neither `while (bytes.hasRemaining())` and `while (rc < bytes.array().length)` which I found at your link is a correct way to write in NIO.

Comment: Is it necessary to deregister OP_READ?

Comment: @mike It isn't *necessary,* but there's not much point in reading new data if you can't write the old data. Let the peer stall rather than trying to read everything new he's sending you, filling up your own read buffers, etc.